# add one NSMuatblearray to another NSMutablearray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have two `nsmutableArray` .  `Arr_jsondata` and second is `tempArray`.

Already `Arr_jsondata` contain the data from json link and display in tableview .

i want to add the tempArray data into `Arr_jsondata` and reload the table using `Arr_jsondata` , because tableview delegate is also used this array to display the data in tableview .

but its always give me an error when i add temp array data into `arr_jsondata` .

```
for (int i=0; i<[Temp_arr_JsonData count]; i++)
{
    NSString *str_brandname = [[Temp_arr_JsonData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"storebrand"];

    NSLog(@"%@",str_brandname);

    NSObject *myNewObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    if ([str_brandname isEqualToString:@"Nike"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Data matched");
        c++;
        myNewObject = [Temp_arr_JsonData objectAtIndex:i];
        [temparray addObject:myNewObject];
    }
}

// arr_JsonData=temparray;
[[arr_JsonData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:temparray] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",temparray);//display all nike related data 
NSLog(@"%@",arr_JsonData);//display null array .

[self.tableView reloadData];

[sender setSelected:YES];
```

in last i want only `tempdata` into `Arr_jsondata` ..... what can i do ?

Comment: Error in this line only 

[[arr_JsonData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:temparray]mutableCopy];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add objects from array. See [this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBD)

```
if (arr_JsonData.count > 0)
    [arr_JsonData addObjectsFromArray: (NSArray*)temparray];
else 
    arr_JsonData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)temparray]
```

Comment: its give an error sigbrd error like 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: Ya. Because you've created with NSArray in some place.At first where did you create `arr_JsonData`? check with that and modify that.

Comment: your second time  written code is right ... its working thanks dear ...

but again one problem is that my tableview delegate used this array but its not display the data from that array .... its display only old data ......

Comment: just post your delegate methods code. I'll look at that.

Comment: storebrand_lbl.text=[[arr_JsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"storebrand"];

Comment: Did you check this method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and also `numberOfSection:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[arr_JsonData addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `arr_JsonData` is not `NSMutableArray` actually which can be judged from the exception description you listed in the answer.  Try this:

```
arr_JsonData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr_JsonData];
[arr_JsonData addObjectsFromArray: temparray];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
NSMutableArray *ar = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:ar1];
```

Just have to initialize array with other array and it will have all contents from other array.

Or this one:

```
NSMutableArray *ar = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:ar1 copyItems:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

`mutableCopy` is defined for `NSArray` not for `NSMutableArray`

```
if ([arr_JsonData count] > 0)
{
    [arr_JsonData addObjectsFromArray: temparray];
}
```